# MySQL Many to One relationship - is a primary key required?

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me understand this as I'm not sure if I should include a primary key in this one, because it doesn't look like I need it.

I have two table structures as follow:

> Table 1: programs
>   program_id
>   cycle_unit
>
> Table 2: program_has_days
>   day
>   week
>   program_id

A program can take many days to complete, so the program has a schedule which is in table 2. The schedule list the day in the week (example day 1 of week 1, then day 3 of week 2) that the program can be completed. So here, it has a one to many relationship. I'm wondering should I put an primary key (id) to table number 2?

I don't think I'll need the primary key, as I won't be referring to the schedule directly. I always refer to the program_id to get the schedule. In this case, program_id can't be the primary key because it is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, good practice;  No, not required.** It's good practice for every table to have a primary key.  This will help you later if you decide you *do* actually need to reference the table's data - even if it's just to delete a few rows without having to specify some *other* unique set of its fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to have many programs running over the same days/weeks, there's no need for a PK on table 2.

But if you're going to have many programs running on the same days/weeks then you may wish to add a PK on Table 2, and have a third joining table between them.  This way, you won't end up with multiple rows in Table 2 for the same day/week combination (ie no point keeping a row for every program that exists on that particular day/week).  Although this would add complexity in checking if an appropriate day/week already exists.

This approach would be particularly relevant if you're interested in efficiently searching on which programs run on a particular day/week (but you've said you're not...).

Another case might be if you need a program to run on multiple schedules (eg the program will run for a few weeks (with different records for each day as you've outline), but then again the program will be re-run in 6 months on a different schedule day/week, etc.  Or perhaps 2 different, but concurrent schedules?) .  This would require a PK on table 2 with a joining table to keep track of the separate schedules OR another key on table 2 to distinguish which instance of a schedule a particular day/week/program combination a record belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for this, very informative. However, a program that runs on multiple schedules, will be re-instantiated. Meaning that a program must run its entire course, then if the user wishes to start again, they will need to reschedule it again. Each program that has run its course must be kept for historic purposes, including its schedule. Hence, only the program_id will ever needed to capture the schedule. Thanks though.